# Additional Include Directories in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, include-path, eigen3

I am getting an error, that a source file cannot be opened. However, I believe I have set up the additional include directory, correctly in vs2015.

This screenshot shows the error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbriP.png)

This screenshot shows the include path:
[include path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAbnd.png)

Comment: Sure, it is unlikely to be stored in the Eigen/Eigen subdirectory.  And you shouldn't use angle brackets since it isn't located in the compiler's default include directories.  Just plain `#include "Dense"`

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was using "Eigen" in both the include path, and the include statement in the cpp file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the `Eigen` from the `#include` or the Additional Include Path.

Also you shouldn't use absolute paths for includes as it means the project is non-portable. Use relative paths.